# .NET Core / EF.Core 3+ add Console logging to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

I'm wondering how to add console logging to EF.Core without getting an "obsolete" warning.

Given:
`DbContextOptionsBuilder<BenchmarkDbContext> builder = ...;`

I tried:

```
builder.UseLoggerFactory(new LoggerFactory().AddConsole())
```

And tried:

```
var factory = new LoggerFactory();

factory.AddProvider(new ConsoleLoggerProvider((a, b) => true, true));

builder.UseLoggerFactory(factory)
```

Comment: I don't like lambda expressions because I don't know how to debug them. 
What does '(a, b) => true, true)' actually do?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the initialization of logger is changed in EFCore 3.x. Try using this:

```
public static readonly ILoggerFactory factory 
    = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => { builder.AddConsole(); });
```

[See details here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3)

Comment: Spot on. Thank you.